# Server or NAS for on-site (maybe no internet) file sharing between computers? With another solution to backup

Tags: networking, nas, storage, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

I'm running a 2-3 man game dev team (game programmer, me, artist and a composer). 
We're slowly reaching certain limitations on storing and sharing assets between team members and it's slowing us down.

We have a few projects running at all times and we'd like to **unify all the assets** we have for **all the projects** into 1 server instead of buying HDDs for every team member. We also need a way to see thumbnails of images as we tend to reuse assets across projects so seeing the thumbnail up front is required for an optimal way of searching.

I'm looking for a solution to have the following:

- have the capabilities of handling concurrent read-write operations as the artist puts assets on the server, I update the game dev docs, the composer uploads and modifies SFX/music files, etc
- have thumbnails ready for images so we don't either have to open images individually or have to wait a few good seconds while we scroll down
- be accessed by minimum 4 on-site devices or more (possibly just computers if a compromise is needed)
- have a readable and easily accessible folder architecture we can relate to, hopefully with custom folder icons that we currently use
- be able to work offline in the way that we buy a router for this network in particular due to paranoia reasons and internet hogging reasons
- possibly have the option to run projects from the disks, say I open Unity or Unreal Engine from the disk so that I don't have to back it up there once I'm done working for the day
- possibly not proprietary hardware so that if something breaks we can fix it fast

This must not be a backup solution, it must be a real time work-storage environment.

I spent all day looking for something like this and as far as I am aware a NAS would not help. Instead we'd need a Windows Server with network mapping or shared folders (we always had problems with making and keeping a homegroup usable).

For backup we'd use external backups.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Server/NAS are essentially the same thing, a computer on your network with hard drives inside it, all that is different is the OS & application running on that computer. Depending on your budget you could go either way. Generating thumbnails could be done by either your PC and/or the nas/server, but you would have to set that up based on the OS's you use and how they look for thumbnails for images. Without benchmarks on your expected throughput of the IO you intend, it's hard to recommend any solution. But any basic server/nas should do.

Comment: Thank you @Vijay . The performance needed is different from project to project as some require a lot of changes and bigger assets and some (such as pixel art) need less space, less changes and overall less IO. I wish I could provide some examples of the heaviest and lightest but I have never done any tests for these unfortunately, sorry :(

Thank you very much for your input :) it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad mentioned in the comments above, the answer is it depends on many other factors, but if you are looking for a quick constrained decision, use any old cpu plus some NAS hdd (rated for 24 hour usage) and install [freenas](https://www.freenas.org)

Or you could buy one readymade from [freenas-mini](https://www.freenas.org/freenas-mini/) or [synology](http://synology.com/)

Or just use and idle windows PC that has good ethernet connection (1 GB or 10 GB) and share folders on that pc.

The bottlenecks for NAS are typically the harddrives and network (depending on the number of users). A desktop cpu is fast enough for any NAS needs.